# A UIView subview doesn't show in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, subview

I'm a newbe on iOS development, I'm trying to make a scroll header like Engadget's app for iPhone, i created a custom UIView to act as a subview for UIScrollView, the algorithm for placing the subviews seems to be ok as I can Scroll the subviews, programatically i change the background color of the views, but the problem is that I can't see anything of the content, just gray backgrounds what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

Promoted is a UIView with two labels and a UIImageView.

```
- (void)layoutScrollSubViews
{
promoted *view = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [sView1 subviews];

// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[promoted class]]  && view.tag > 0)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
        frame.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
        frame.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
        view.frame = frame;

        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
    }
}

// set the content size so it can be scrollable
[sView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth), [sView1 bounds].size.height)];

}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad{    
NSUInteger i;
for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
{

    promoted *p = [[promoted alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 187)];

    p.title.text = @"Test 1";
    p.num.text = @"1/1";
    p.num.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
    p.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(.9/i) green:(.9/i) blue:(.9/i) alpha:1];

    p.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion

    [sView1 addSubview:p];
    [p release];
}

[self layoutScrollSubViews];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: aside: Obj-C naming convention: classes capitalized (i.e. `Promoted`); Cocoa loose naming convention: view subclasses have the word `View` in them (i.e. `PromotedView`)

Comment: you prob'ly want to call `[super viewDidLoad]` at the beginning of your implementation

Comment: we would have to see your `promoted` class to know anything about the subviews and why they might not be displaying (or if they exist at all) - all we know is that it's a subview of `UIView` (or `addSubview:` would fail).

Comment: your `[[promoted alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 187)]` could prob'ly use the `kScrollObjHeight` and `kScrollObjWidth` as a good coding practice (but make no difference - just a comment since you said you were new to iOS)

Comment: Hoe does `promoted` perform layout?

Comment: This is the (renamed) PromotedView class:

   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


  @interface PromotedView : UIView <NSCoding>{
 IBOutlet UILabel *num;
 IBOutlet UILabel *title;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
   }

  
   @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *num;
   @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
   @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *img;

   @end

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:
1. Add your image view and labels directly to `scrollView`
2. also alloc your label and ImageView before adding them to your `UIView`(and don't forgot to release them when requirement is finish, in respective scope)

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, UIScrollView is a **weird buggy** control released by apple. Don't know why it behaves abnormal when added through nib file. I always try to create UIScrollView programmatically and add subviews to it by allocating them programmatically as well.

May be it would sound strange, but it works for me most of the time!